# Exclude query condition if argument of function is null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Is it possible to ignore `cb.equal(myClass.get(MyClass_.token), token)` if `token` is null without duplicating query? I do not want to pack it into huge if that completely duplicates the query (with just skipping one condition).

```
private MyClass find(String code, String token) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyClass> cq = cb.createQuery(MyClass.class);
    Root<MyClass> myClass = cq.from(MyClass.class);
    cq.select(myClass).where(
            cb.and(cb.equal(myClass.get(MyClass_.code), code),
                    cb.equal(myClass.get(MyClass_.token), token),
                    cb.greaterThan(myClass.get(MyClass_.expirationDate), DateUtils.getTime())
            ));
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Something like below. Note I just text edited your code and didnt actually check for syntax errors or compile it

```
private MyClass find(String code, String token) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MyClass> cq = cb.createQuery(MyClass.class);
    Root<MyClass> myClass = cq.from(MyClass.class);
    Predicate predicate = cb.and(
            cb.equal(myClass.get(MyClass_.code), code),
            cb.greaterThan(myClass.get(MyClass_.expirationDate), DateUtils.getTime())
    );
    if (token != null)
        predicate = cb.and(predicate, cb.equal(myClass.get(MyClass_.token), token));

    cq.select(myClass).where(predicate);
}
```